# Debug com arquivos min no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, debug, grunt

Criei uma task no `Grunt` para automaticamente o `concat` e `uglify` nos meus arquivos `.js` do Angular para melhorar a performance e também para não precisar ficar inserindo um novo arquivo toda vez que crio um controller, por exemplo. Porém, com isso, os erros no console passaram a ficar incoerentes obviamente. 
Então gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de criar um `.map` (como já faço nos meus .min do `Bootstrap` com `LESS`) ou algo do gênero para facilitar a tarefa de `debug`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não precisa de `concat` e `uglify` para tempo de desenvolvimento - na verdade você está adicionando *overhead* ao concatenar e minificar todo o conteúdo após cada alteração.

Se você está usando a notação tradicional para os *tasks* do Grunt, você provavelmente tem um chamado `build`. Remova o passo `uglify`. algo assim:

```
grunt.registerTask("build", [
    "concat:all",
    "concat_css:all",
    "bower_concat:all"
]);
```

Adicione um task adicional para preparar o projeto para modo *produção*:

```
grunt.registerTask("build-dist", [
    "concat:all",
    "concat_css:all",
    "cssmin:all",
    "bower_concat:all",
    "uglify:all"
]);
```

Execute o task `build-dist` apenas quando estiver pronto para enviar o projeto para produção.

Comment: Concatenar também não é legal? :(

Comment: @MatheusWeissheimerSartoretto Concatenar é maneiríssimo, porque contribui para a redução do tempo de download quando sua aplicação estiver em produção. Para desenvolvimento local, entretanto, é desnecessário - você está literalmente na máquina onde o arquivo está localizado.

Comment: Mas não é muito mais trabalhoso ficar adicionando todos os meus .js lá no index e depois ter que deletar pra adicionar o .min.js?

Comment: @MatheusWeissheimerSartoretto Isso não será necessário se seu task `build` apenas concatenar a versão não-minificada, deixando a versão '.min.js' a cargo do task `build-dist`. Isso vai da sua escolha de configuração de tempo de desenvolvimento.